# Redirect 301 or RedirectMatch 301 not working for me

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, httpd.conf

**So this is my scenario:**

I have 1 static IP and 2 servers. 1 server is a web server the other is a mail server. I have a router as a hardware firewall with all the ports are set that require passthrough to internal ip addresses .

If a user types the url http://www.domain.com they see that website. If the user wants to access webmail they type in the url http://mail.domain.com but still see http://www.domain.com

I have set the webmail domain to be accessible via port 8080 on the mail server and if the user types the url http://mail.domain.com:8080 it works no problem but not with http://mail.domain.com.

**So this is my issue:**

In my httpd.conf I want to setup a Redirect 301 so that when the user types in http://mail.domain.com they get redirected to http://mail.domain.com:8080

I'd prefer not to use .htaccess and keep the directives in the httpd.conf

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a virtual host on your main web server that responds to web requests for the "mail.domain.com" address.  Take a look at the [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) documentation on the Apache website.  You'll also need a mod_rewrite rule to do the redirection.  Your configuration would look something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mail.domain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*) http://mail.domain.com:8080/\1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Rewrite is useless if a virtualhost is created, RedirectMatch will be probably faster

Comment: what are you talking about radius? Rewrite is perfectly fine in a virtualhost as listed above. The code is a little broken (use $1 not \1) but other than that it's good.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least 2 way to do this:

1. Create 2 [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) one for www.domain.com and one for mail.domain.com and then put your RedirectMatch directive in the second one.
   You could also use the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive in the mail.domain.com virtual host to make it working like a reverse proxy and have mail.domaine.com:80 working directly without redirection
2. Use mod_rewrite like this to only redirect for the mail.domain.com url with a rule like that

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mail.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mail.domain.com:8080/$1 [R=301]

   with mod_rewrite you can also do a reverse proxy with a rule like (mail.domain.com should resolve to the internal IP)

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mail.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mail.domain.com:8080/$1 [P]